# Отследить остановку ввода на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

Есть компонент, который получает данные от пользователя из инпута и отправляет запросы на изменение поля. Перекинуть отправку запроса на блюр инпута я не могу, поэтому хочу отправлять запрос когда пользователь не вводил данных n десятых секунд, или хотя бы ограничить частоту отправки запроса. Информации по тому как и можно ли вообще такое реализовать я не нашел, а очень нужно

Comment: а почему `onBlur` нельзя? если так, то есть `onChange` еще - эффект тот же

Comment: Т.е. отправка происходит автоматически после последнего ввода? Даже если фокус с элемента не убран? Фокус->Ввод->Остановка->Прошло 10сек-> Отправка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если я правильно понял задачу, то вот наклепал: https://jsfiddle.net/eLsu4yxp/ Создаём интервал и обнуляем таймер при вводе что-то пользователем

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     textValue: '',
      counter: 0,
      sendTime: 15
    }
    this.interval = null;
  }
  
  changeText(e) {
   const val = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
     counter: 0
    })
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = null;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
     if (this.state.counter == this.state.sendTime) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        return;
      }
      this.setState({
       counter: this.state.counter + 1
      });
    }, 1000);
   this.setState({
     textValue: val
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <label>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.textValue} onChange={this.changeText.bind(this)}/> 
          Запрос будет отправлен когда пройдет {this.state.sendTime} секунд после ввода: {this.state.counter}
          {this.state.sendTime == this.state.counter ? 'TimeSend' : ' Waiting...'}
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать в компоненте такой метод

```
async saveToServer() {
    this.saveTimer = null;
    // отправляем запрос на сервер, делаем что еще нужно 
}
```

При изменении инпута делаем

```
this.onTimer = async () => {
    await this.saveToServer();
}

if (this.saveTimer) {
    clearTimeout(this.saveTimer);
}

this.saveTimer = setTimeout(this.onTimer, 100*n);
```

И еще должен быть какой-то такой *componentWillUnmount()*

```
async componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.saveTimer) {
        clearTimeout(this.saveTimer);
        await this.saveToServer();
    }
}
```